# ms-access SQL linked sheet row order retention

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to guarantee row order in a table derived from a linked sheet?   I seem to occasionally lose row order (which unfortunately has meaning) when I select from a Linked Sheet while looping over a number of sheets & WB.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , "linked_sheet ", sfile, False, "some_sheet!A1:U100"
CurrentDb().Execute "select '" & identifier & "' as id1, " & identifier2 & " as id2,  i.* into temp_table from linked_sheet i"
CurrentDb().Execute "alter temp_table add column ky counter primary key"
```

The keys are correctly ordinal, but the rows are not the same as the original spreadsheet.

The problem is intermittent and does not occur on the same Sheet/WB every time.

If I catch the error, then go back and rerun the same code, it will return correct original row order as it appears in the sheet.

The rows are not missing, they are moved to a different location in temp_table. 
I'm holding the WB in memory while querying the linked_sheet could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wax philosophically, you should not care about the order of rows inserted into the target table. That is at the db engine's discretion. The only time you should be concerned is upon presentation, when you select from the temp table. This is the most likely reason that "order by" is not supported by this syntax.

May I inquire why it is an issue?

Other databases use a syntax "insert into x from (select * from y order by z)", where the "order by" controls the order in which the rows are presented to the insert statement. But it still remains that the order of data in the db should not be relevant.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd love it if the data were treated that way, but unfortunately, some data has meaning only in it's spacial relation to other data.  ('A' belongs the data 2 cells up and one left.)  And/Or there are multiple 'Tables' in each sheet where each 'Table' is identifiable geographically.  In fact, sorting that mess out is precisely the problem I'm solving for. Munge

Comment: Not to tell you what to do, but can you get the "tables" onto their own excel tabs. This relates directly to tables in the jet(access/excel) engine. It may make the data easier to visualize, which leads to figuring out the proper joins.

Comment: OK,  I take this to mean, "DB's aren't ordered and therefore don't do this.  It isn't possible".